# .htaccess - is it possible to have a combination of static and dynamic url?

Tags: .htaccess

At the moment I use the following code to convert dynamic URLs to static in my .htaccess file:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC]

RewriteCond %{THE_REQUEST} ^[A-Z]{3,9}\ /index\.php\?page=([^&]+)\ HTTP/
RewriteRule ^index\.php$ http://www.mywebsite.com/%1? [R=301,L]
```

What I'd like to know is if it's possible to change this rule so that pages can be access via `www.mywebsite.com/news` but also additional `$_GET` information can appended like so: `www.mywebsite.com/news?id=1`

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You want to take a look at the [QSA flag](http://httpd.apache.org/docs/current/rewrite/flags.html#flag_qsa), which will append query strings after you constructed one:

```
RewriteRule ^([a-z0-9_\-]+)$ /index.php?page=$1 [L,NC,QSA]
```

This makes it so a request for `http://www.mywebsite.com/news?id=1` gets internally rewritten to: `/index.php?page=news&id=1`